# PHP CSV read with MySQL insert (utf8)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Anyone able to provide working example of CSV read and MySQL insert - all with utf8? Cannot figure out how to do this (long hours ...). MySQL collation all utf8mb4_unicode_ci (database, table, columns).

Thanks for help!

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_select_db("test");

if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size']) && $_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0){

    $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
    utf8_encode(fgets($file));
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    do {
        if ($data){
            $data = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (id,text) VALUES 
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."','".addslashes($data[1])."'
            )");        
        }
    }
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    header('Location: index.php'); die;
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
<input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" accept-charset="utf-8"/> 
<button type=submit>UPLOAD</button>
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using LOAD DATA INFILE instead

> LOAD DATA INFILE can be used to read files obtained from external sources. For example, many programs can export data in comma-separated values (CSV) format,
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Here we go. This is working example of PHP CSV read with MySQL insert for utf8.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");

if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size']) && $_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0){

        $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file,"r");
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8mb4");
        mysql_set_charset('utf8mb4');

        do {
            if ($data){
                utf8_encode($data);
                mb_strtolower($data[0], 'UTF-8');
                mb_strtolower($data[1], 'UTF-8');

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (id,text) VALUES 
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."','".addslashes($data[1])."'
                )");        
            }
        }
        while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
        header('Location: index.php'); die;
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
    <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" accept-charset="utf-8"/> 
    <button type=submit>UPLOAD</button>
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```